# merge update oracle unable to get a stable set of rows

Tags: oracle, merge

I am trying to update a table in Oracle based on another table (inner join) but the matching fields match on more than 1 row so I get an error:

> unable to get a stable set of rows

```
    MERGE INTO C
    USING D
    ON (C.SYSTEM = D.SYSTEM)
    WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET C.REF_CD = D.CODE,
               C.REF_DT = TO_DATE('12/05/2017', 'MM/DD/YYYY')
       WHERE C.CODE = '123'
       AND D.CODE IS NOT NULL
       AND C.CLOSED = 'N'
       AND C.RCVD_DT >= TO_DATE('12/01/2017', 'MM/DD/YYYY')
       AND C.RCVD_DT <= TO_DATE('12/04/2017', 'MM/DD/YYYY')
       AND SUBSTR(C.SSN,7,3) >= D.FROM
       AND SUBSTR(C.SSN,7,3) <= D.TO;
```

As a SELECT statement, I can pull this information using an inner join. But as a merge statement, I get the above error. SYSTEM is the only matching data in both tables.  How can I rewrite the above in a way that it will not error out?

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you are saying. Are there duplicate values in the SYSTEM column in table D? If there are (that would be the meaning of the error you got), then you have a fatal logical flaw in what you are trying to do; you won't be able to do it no matter what programming language you use (what query you write, etc.) Think about it: you want to set C.REF_CD to the value of D.CODE, but there are two or more rows in table D from which to read values for D.CODE. Which of those values should be used for the update? Oracle won't make that choice for you!

Comment: By the way, "not error out" is the wrong goal for what you are doing. (Unfortunately, many developers just want to avoid errors, regardless of whether the resulting code is actually correct). What you do want is a problem statement that makes sense (yours doesn't seem to, at this time), and then solve that problem CORRECTLY. "Not error out" is easy - you can select the max or min D.CODE from all those returned by the join. Is **that** the correct answer to your problem? The business user, not the software engineer, should decide that!

Comment: The D table has 3 digits in the TO and FROM column. This is a range. It also has a CODE column assigned to that range.There are only a few systems, so system is duplicated in many rows. System is the only matching column in both the C and D tables, thus the only column I can join on. I am looking at the 3 digits in the C table and finding that range in the D table, and assigning the code in the C table based on the code for that range in the D table. Because of multiple system values matching in both tables, the error occurs.

Comment: If I write the above statement as an INNER JOIN SELECT statement, it works fine. But since you can't do INNER JOIN in an oracle UPDATE statement, I can't write it that way, which would have made my life a lot easier. Thus, I have attempted to write it as a merge, which oracle accepts, but then I get the error.

Comment: To clarify, there are only duplicate entries for system. But when you add the range, there is no duplicate. But since it is joining on system, effectively, it is having a problem with the duplicate rows for system.

Comment: Also, this isn't permanent code. This is a one time update needed to make these assignments to 500+ rows in production asap.

Comment: Try moving your unique join conditions from the WHERE clause into the ON clause where the join actually happens.

Answer (score 5):

I am going to show what the source of this error is.
Consider the below simple example:

```
CREATE TABLE A_100(
  x_system int,
  val int
);

INSERT INTO a_100 values( 1, 100 );
INSERT INTO a_100 values( 2, 200 );

CREATE TABLE B_100(
  x_system int,
  val int
);

INSERT INTO b_100 values( 1, 1100 );
INSERT INTO b_100 values( 2, 2000 );
INSERT INTO b_100 values( 2, 3000 );

commit;
```

---

Now please consider this join:

```
SELECT *
FROM A_100 a
JOIN B_100 b
ON a.x_system = b.x_system AND a.x_system = 1
;

| X_SYSTEM | VAL | X_SYSTEM |  VAL |
|----------|-----|----------|------|
|        1 | 100 |        1 | 1100 |
```

the above query gives one unique record from the table `B_100`. If you use this join condition in a merge statement, the merge will run without any error:

```
MERGE INTO A_100 a
USING B_100 b
ON ( a.x_system = b.x_system AND a.x_system = 1)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET a.val = b.val
;

1 row merged.
```

---

Now please consider the below join:

```
SELECT *
FROM A_100 a
JOIN B_100 b
ON a.x_system = b.x_system AND a.x_system = 2
;

| X_SYSTEM | VAL | X_SYSTEM |  VAL |
|----------|-----|----------|------|
|        2 | 200 |        2 | 2000 |
|        2 | 200 |        2 | 3000 |
```

The above join, for one record from `A_100` gives two records from `B_100`.

If you try to use MERGE with the above join condition you will get the following:

```
MERGE INTO A_100 a
USING B_100 b
ON ( a.x_system = b.x_system AND a.x_system = 2)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET a.val = b.val
;

Error report -
ORA-30926: unable to get a stable set of rows in the source tables
```

---

Oracle simply says you :

> The query for one record from the left table returned two values:
>   2000 and 3000 from the right table. 
>   I can not assign two values from the right table to a single scalar field of the left table, this is impossible.
>   Please change the join condition so that it gives only one unique
>   record from the right table for each record in the left table