# Execution (10: 46): ORA-30926: unable to get a stable set of rows in the source tables

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-merge

When I am running this query :

```
 MERGE INTO AMDW.DIMSECURITY_08052018 OUTER_TAB
     USING (Select DISTINCT DS.SECURITYKEY,DCQ.currencycode From AMDW.DIMSECURITY_08052018 DS inner join AMDW.FACTTRANSACTION FT
on DS.securitykey =FT.SECuritykey inner join AMDW.DIMELEMENTARYTRANSACTIONTYPE  DETT on DETT.ELEMENTARYTRANSACTIONTYPEKEY=FT.ELEMENTARYTRANSACTIONTYPEKEY 
 inner join  AMDW.DIMCURRENCY  DCQ on DCQ.CURRENCYKEY = FT.QUOTATIONCURRENCYKEY
where legacyholdtype='FRWD' and DS.WISCURRENT=1 and DS.wlastupdatetimestamp <= to_date('09-02-2018','DD-MM-YYYY') and FT.NOMINALFACTOR=1 and 
 upper(DETT.ELEMENTARYTRANSACTIONCATEGORY) <> 'MATURITY AND EXERCISE' ) INNER_TAB
  ON (    (OUTER_TAB.SECURITYKEY = INNER_TAB.SECURITYKEY))
WHEN MATCHED
THEN
   UPDATE SET OUTER_TAB.LegacyBUYQUOTATIONCURRENCY = INNER_TAB.currencycode ;
```

It is throwing an error:

> [Error] Execution (10: 46): ORA-30926: unable to get a stable set of rows in the source tables.

I want to update the duplicate rows.

```
SELECT SECURITYKEY,currencycode, count(*)
FROM (
     Select  DS.SECURITYKEY,DCQ.currencycode From AMDW.DIMSECURITY_08052018 DS inner join AMDW.FACTTRANSACTION FT
on DS.securitykey =FT.SECuritykey inner join AMDW.DIMELEMENTARYTRANSACTIONTYPE  DETT on DETT.ELEMENTARYTRANSACTIONTYPEKEY=FT.ELEMENTARYTRANSACTIONTYPEKEY 
 inner join  AMDW.DIMCURRENCY  DCQ on DCQ.CURRENCYKEY = FT.QUOTATIONCURRENCYKEY
where legacyholdtype='FRWD' and DS.WISCURRENT=1 and DS.wlastupdatetimestamp <= to_date('09-02-2018','DD-MM-YYYY') and FT.NOMINALFACTOR=1 and 
 upper(DETT.ELEMENTARYTRANSACTIONCATEGORY) <> 'MATURITY AND EXERCISE'
    )
group by SECURITYKEY,currencycode
having count(*) > 1
```

Result:

```
SECURITYKEY   currencycode count
31243412    USD 2
31243422    USD 2
31243426    AUD 2
31243324    EUR 3
31243338    USD 2
31243336    GBP 2
31243366    BRL 2
31243423    GBP 2
31243346    GBP 2
31243429    EUR 2
31243343    GBP 2
31243425    USD 2
31243431    NZD 2
31243333    USD 3
31243330    GBP 2
31243341    USD 2
31243342    GBP 2
31243348    GBP 2
31243328    GBP 2
31243337    GBP 2
31243433    AUD 2
31243434    NZD 2
31243367    BRL 2
31243428    NZD 2
31243427    EUR 2
31243432    EUR 2
31243347    USD 2
```

Comment: Does the inner query `Select DISTINCT DS.SECURITYKEY,DCQ.currencycode From ...` return any security keys with multiple currencies? (Not just `count(*) > 1` when grouped by key and currency). If so you're be trying to update the same matching rows twice.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [merge update oracle unable to get a stable set of rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47659844/merge-update-oracle-unable-to-get-a-stable-set-of-rows)

Comment: There are quite a few questions already on this error message. https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=ORA-30926