# merge statement giving me the "unable to get a stable set of rows" error

Tags: sql, oracle, merge

I have two tables that I'm trying to merge on a set of common columns:

```
table1    
project|supplies|part|ship|delivery
A1|B2|C3|01012018|02012018
A1|B3|C4|01022018|02022018
A2|B1|C1|01032018|02032018
```

and

```
table2  
project|supplies|part|amount
A1|B2|C3|100
A1|B3|C4|200
A2|B1|C1|300
```

The expected output is:

```
project|supplies|part|amount|ship|delivery
A1|B2|C3|100|01012018|02012018
A1|B3|C4|200|01022018|02022018
A2|B1|C1|300|01032018|02032018
```

The code that I'm trying to use is below, but it throws the `ORA-30926: unable to get a stable set of rows in the source tables` error

```
MERGE INTO table2 t2
    USING (select DISTINCT projects,supplies,part,ship,deliver FROM table1) t1
    ON (t2.project = t1.project)          
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET t2.ship = t1.ship,
            t2.deliver = t1.delivery
WHERE t1.part = t2.part
    AND t1.project = t2.project
    AND t1.supplies = t2.supllies;
```

I also tried:

```
MERGE INTO table2 t2
    USING table1 t1
    ON (t2.project = t1.project
    AND t2.part = t1.part
    AND t2.supplies = t1.supplies)          
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET t2.ship = t1.ship,
            t2.deliver = t1.delivery;
```

But get the same error

Comment: you table2 does not have the ship  and the deliver columns

Comment: I've just tried to reproduce the exception with data you've provided - everything is ok, the table2 has been merged. Generally that exception means that you're trying to to update the same row of the target table multiple times. So I believe that the problem in a data of joined columns. Try to join tables without merging to find duplicates

Comment: Possible duplicate of [merge update oracle unable to get a stable set of rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47659844/merge-update-oracle-unable-to-get-a-stable-set-of-rows)

Comment: @YuriyTsarkov I updated the data tables to be better representative of what I have going on. basically each row in both tables is unique, the only difference between the two tables is that one has an amount column and the other has the date columns

Comment: To rephrase what others have said, you have more than 1 ship/deliver combination for one or more projects,supplies,part combinations. try `select count(*) c , projects,supplies,part from table1 group by projects,supplies,part having count(*) > 1;` This will show the offending records.